# What is a linear combination, exactly?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm used to the definition of linear combination used in linear algebra textbooks.
I'm reading the book Algebra by Artin and on page 357 he says:

> If $R$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of integer polynomials, the notation $(2,x)$ stands for the ideal of linear combinations of $2$ and $x$ with integer polynomial coefficients.

According to the definition above, the term $x\cdot x+2 = x^2+2$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $2$, which doesn't feel like linear to me.

Here is my question: What is the definition of a linear combination?

My confusion may arise because in a vector space there is no such thing as product of vectors.

Comment: I just did search on the book's pdf for 'of integer polynomials' and couldn't find this. What's the number of theorem, example, whatever? It's not on page 357 of the book's second edition either.

Comment: @GitGud Page 357, first edition. Just below equation 3.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a finite set of things, like $\{ x, y, z, w \}$.  Let's pretend they are just variables.  If we want to talk about a linear combination of these things, we first need to know what our "scalars" will be.

If we take our scalars to be all real numbers $\Bbb R$, then a linear combination of $\{x,y,z,w \}$ is a *finite sum* of these things with *coefficients from the set of scalars*, here $\Bbb R$.  So $\pi x + \sqrt{2} y$ is a linear combination since it is really $\pi x + \sqrt{2} y + 0z + 0w$.  As you can see, my coefficients, which are scalars, come from $\Bbb R$.

If we decided we wanted our scalars to be $\Bbb Z$, the integers, then the above would not be a linear combination of elements in $\{x,y,z, w\}$ since some scalars are not integers.  But an example of a linear combination with coefficients from $\Bbb Z$ is $19x + 5y - 3w$.

Now, we could choose our scalars to be wacky things, like the set of all $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices with real entries, for example.  Then a linear combination of the elements of $\{x,y,z,w\}$ over this set of scalars could be $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 9 & 2 \end{bmatrix}z$.

---

Now, in your example, our *coefficients*, or scalars, happen to be **integer polynomials**.  For example, in your example, a scalar would be $3x^{2} + 5x$, since this is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and the polynomial itself is acting as our coefficient.  So, if we want to write a linear combination of $\{2, x \}$ with integer coefficients, we better write $oneThing * 2 + twoThing* x$ where $oneThing$ and $twoThing$ are coefficients (in this case, they better be polynomials with integer coefficients since these are our scalars).  This is why $x^{2} + 2 = x \cdot x + 2$ is a linear combination.  The $x$ has coefficient $x$, which is itself a polynomial with integer coefficients and thus a scalar.

---

If you now understand what a linear combination is above, the general way to write the definition of a linear combination of, say $\{ 2, x\}$ with scalars as polynomials with integer coefficients is to say "a linear combination is of the form $c_{1}2 + c_{2}x$ where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are scalars, i.e., polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: Ok, what about the term "linear" in the expression "linear combination"? Is there anything "linear" in the definition?

Comment: @limoe If we are writing a linear combination of $\{x,y,z,w\}$ over a set of scalars, denote them $c_{i}$, then a linear comb is $c_{1}x + c_{2}y + c_{3}z + c_{4}w$.  It's "linear" because all we are doing is adding scalar mult of these to each other.  In your example of $x^{2} + 2 = x\cdot x + 2$, I can see why you are confused, since we are multiplying $x$ with itself, which seems to not be linear.  But what we are actually doing is multiplying the *scalar* $x$ with the $x$ from $\{x, 2\}$.  We are allowed to do this, since here $x$ is a polynomial with integer coeff., and thus a scalar.

Comment: ok, now I get it, it is just a matter of "interpretation" on the symbol "x" in our expression, but linear combination is a term that may cause confusion, if there is nothing "linear" in the sense we are used to, why not call it just a "combination"? Thank you for your time.